# How can I add Lens Flares/Halos?

Tags: compositing-nodes, shaders

Is there an addon, or an easy way to add [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare) effects or [light aberrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_%28optics%29#Aberrations) in Blender? I've been using Blender for a while now, and it's very time consuming to always have to export to another software to do them, and sometimes it's impossible if the scene is complex.

Comment: Do you mean light glares/flares that analyzes an image and add the flares/glares on top, or custom flares (i.e. you position it where you want it)?

Comment: either one I guess. I know blender has the com positing capabilities with the glare node and such, but it's not very versatile...

Comment: In what way? The glare controls are robust enough, and if you want more or less flare, you can adjust the contrast.

Answer (score 9):

**lens-flare shader**

There is an OSL [lens-flare shader](http://blendbits.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/lens-flare-shader-for-blender-cycles.html) by iReboot (aka Dylan Whiteman) which may interest you.

From his blog post referring to a lens-flare shader originally written for the Renderman language by `Larry Gritz & Tony Apodaca of pixar`, iReboot writes:

> I decided to try and port this to OSL - (...) I added a few features, such as
>   user definable images for lens-flare elements and have got to a point
>   where the shader can now be released.(...) - along with video tutorial links

Comment: but this blog is for 2.67, the nodes have already changed, so how do you adapt it?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the OSL shader mentioned by zeffi, you can try these:

- **Blender Internal(2.79 or less) only:**
  You can use the *Halo* material with the [*Flare* option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/materials/special_effects/halo.html#flare-panel) enabled to fake lens flares.
- **Cycles and BI:**
  Using [*Compositing nodes*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/introduction.html):
  You can use a *Glare node* set to *Ghosts* to make a lens flair.
  For chromatic aberration, you could use a [*Lens Distortion node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/distort/lens_distortion.html) with the *Dispersion* value set to something greater than zero.