# Is It Possible To Create A Lens Flare In 3d Scene (Cycles)? Without Compositing?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am trying to create a scene looking through a dirty window or Lens and I am wondering if it is possible to create Real time Lens flare with Cycles.

Shining the light directly at the camera with a dirty glass plane (lens) in front of it. Is there some kind of node set up to get the glass to refract a "lens flare" that the camera could pick up.

Doesn't have to be realistic.

[image]

I feel like it can be done, but I can't control it at all.

[image]

Comment: Something like the osl shader in the answer to this question maybe? http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1864/15924

Comment: Awesome I will check that out, don't know much about OSL shaders though.  I will definitely check that out.